# What is the best way to transfer Magento setup to another folder?

Tags: magento-1.7, server-setup

I have Magento in the store/ folder on my server. I want to be able to put it at the root. So that users don't have to see in the URL store/. I have already configured Magento.

So how can I bring my Magento setup to the root of my server?

Also is it the best idea? Or should I keep it in the store/ folder and use .htaccess to point to the store/ folder to remove the store/ from the URL?

Comment: Do you have SSH access and/or do you have your project in a proper version control system in place?

Comment: Nop, I am using a share hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the files and folders from `root/store` to `root`, change in the table `core_config_data` the values for path =  `web/unsecure/base_url`, `web/unsecure/base_link_url`, `web/unsecure/base_skin_url`, `web/unsecure/media_url` and `web/unsecure/base_js_url` to not include the `/store`.
Do the same for pat = `web/secure/...` (all of the above).
Make sure you have 777 rights on `media` and `cache` folders and their subfolders.